# Two-way binding with mutliple inputs

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm a beginner in Angular (I'm doing Angular 2, not Angular.js), and was trying to write something that would take two inputs and do something with them without any button-click (like two-way binding). For example, if I have two text inputs, I would like for another component (let's say a label) to contain both strings concatenated. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you tried using two way data binding? https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you are stuck please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic template would look something like

```
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="second">
    <label>{{first}} {{second}}</label>
```

This template is using two-way data binding using `ngModel` directive

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible. First, you have to get user input, like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-key-up2',
  template: `
    <input #box (keyup)="onKeyInput1(box.value)">
    <input #box (keyup)="onKeyInput2(box.value)">
    <p>{{input1}}{{input2}}</p>
  `
})
export class KeyUpComponent_v2 {
  input2 = ''
  input1 = '';
  onKeyInput1(value: string) {
    this.input1 = value
  }
 onKeyInput2(value: string) {
    this.input2 = value
  }
}
```

Then, just show the output inside your chosen tag, like so `{{ }}`.
Reference: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

EDIT: Oh, right, you could also use `[(ng-model)]`, see the above answer.

Comment: please, see the answer of Saksham. Angular are "closely" to  use NgModel or ReactiveForm or template variable reference. Use (keyup) is a "javascript style"